# React won't render the first object of the array while rendering inside *.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

while rendering the SearchCard component, it doesnt show the first object of the array-

```
    const cardArrayTrackSearch = this.state.searchtrack.map((user, i) => {
        return (
            <SearchCard key={i}
            reload={this.props.reload}
            song={this.state.searchtrack[i].trackName} 
            artist={this.state.searchtrack[i].artistName}
            art={this.state.searchtrack[i].artworkUrl100}/>
                );
            
    })
```

this is my render() of the SearchCard component

```
    render() {

    const titleCase = (str) => {
       var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
       for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
           splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
       }
       return splitStr.join(' '); 
    }

    var {song, artist,art} = this.props;
    song = song.replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '');
    song = titleCase(song);

    return (

        <div className='button bg-image1 light-blue dib br3 grow tc bw2 shadow-5 flex items-center bb b--black-10' onClick={() => this.getUrl(`${song} ${artist} lyrics`)} >
            <img className= '' src={art} alt='artwork' />
            <dl className="pl3 flex-auto">
              <dt className="clip">Title</dt>
              <dd className="ml0 white truncate w-100">{song}</dd> 
              <dt className="clip">Artist</dt>
              <dd className="ml0 gray truncate w-100">{artist}</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        );
    }
```

while rendering the first object is skipped and it starts rendering from the second object of the array this.state.searchtrack[].

Comment: `map` doesn't just skip entries. If the entry is there, it'll be processed. The only thing that comes to mind is if it's a *sparse* array, the gaps in it are not visited. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: why don't replace this.state.searchtrack[i] with user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the styling, the tacheon classes were misspelled. the map return was correct